# Deploying a web service as an app for Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to access a webservice through an Android app? So basically a user would be purchasing access to the site by paying for the app? Then deploy rich content to the user through the browser? If so, is it then possible to authenticate who has access to the site from the webserver without the need for signin or signup?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to access a webservice through an Android app?**

Yes, and many many apps do so. Not all web-services are equally friendly for App development though. Does the webservice in question have an API designed *(read: usable)* for this?

**So basically a user would be purchasing access to the site by paying for the app?**

Yes, if its your web-service, or a web-service that allows this type of licensing/usage.

*Note: I, **as a user**, dislike Apps that are only facades for  mobile websites/web-services- Id rather visit a mobile page/service in my phone's web browser.*

**Then deploy rich content to the user through the browser?**

Yes, depends on the content though, this isn't the only way for an App to interact with a web-service. See my note above.

**If so, is it then possible to authenticate who has access to the site from the webserver without the need for signin or signup?**

Yes, I am not sure if there are existing solutions for this, but it would definitely be possible to roll your own.

Comment: I'd like to tap into my existing skill set rather taking on the challenge of learning new languages and frameworks to deploy my project. It would involve a flash based game (so it would require plugin) PHP and MYSQL data management it would save me about 12 months development time.

Comment: @woodscreative, the idea isn't to redevelop your App for android if it is better as a web app, the idea is to guide the users to the URL that the App would be showing them. That being said, people DO have Apps on the different marketplaces that are essentially a browser window directed at a specific url- so they must see some benefit in doing so. I'd guess making an 'App' in that way could garner higher visibility/traffic.

Comment: Because I don't need access to the devices features there really is not point me building a native mobile app. It seems that the App market is just a good place to market and monetize content that users usually would take for granted out on the internet and like you say increase visibility and traffic.